# How can black hole rotate?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, angular-momentum, event-horizon, singularities

I was reading about black holes and I've found part saying that black hole is a point and anther saying that black hole can rotate. However the points are dimensionless, so they can't rotate - **How can black hole rotate then? Can non rotating black hole start rotating?**
I rather don't know too much about physic so even basic explanation would be great to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a singularity in a black hole rotate if it's just a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103232/)