# How is rotational information transferred to a singularity?

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, singularities

If some mass spirals into a black hole the conservation of angular momentum means that the result will have to spin (at least to my albeit limited understanding). But if the singularity is a point, then how is the rotational 'information' transferred from the mass to the black hole? If it was the earth I could see the $x$ vector of the contact force being applied to the surface but a point has no surface.

Comment: duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103232/

Comment: Bear in mind that what happens inside the event horizon is irrelevant to the rest of the universe, since no information can escape the event horizon. So it's best to think of the angular momentum, mass, and charge of a BH as properties of the spacetime *outside* the horizon. There are various questions on this topic (mostly in regard to mass) on this site, but also see https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/black_gravity.html