# How to explain spin for a 14-year old teen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

How do you explain the concept of spin in QM to a 14-year old teen, and why it isn't a vector as in the classical notion of angular momentum?

Comment: See also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147/what-are-some-useful-ways-to-imagine-the-concept-of-spin-as-it-relates-to-subato

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to explain without using (relatively to a 14 year-old) advanced mathematics. After all, this is a purely QM effect that cannot be pictured.

Comment: Spin is a property like colour or mass. But the one thing that it isn't, is actual "spin". In this sense it is just a name.