# Representations of the Poincare group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

Which type of states carry the irreducible unitary [representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Poincar%C3%A9_group) of the Poincare group? Multi-particle states or Single-particle states?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21801/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22449/2451 and links therein.

Comment: by definition, single particle states are irreps of Poincare or any other group of interest. Multiparticle states belong to symemtrized (bosons) or antisymmetrized (fermions) products thereof

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially by definition (due to Wigner), **one-particle** Hilbert spaces of elementary particles support unitary strongly continuous **irreducible** representations of Poincaré group.

Conversely, any **multi-particle** Hilbert space, with either fixed or undefined number of particles either identical or distinguishable, **cannot be irreducible** under the action  of the associated representation of  Poincaré group.

**Proof.** A multi-particle representation is the tensor product of the representations in each factor one-particle subspace. If $P_\mu$ denotes the total four-momentum operator of the system of particles, the bounded unitary operator $e^{i a P_\mu P^\mu}$ ($a\in \mathbb R$) commutes with all the unitary operators of the tensor representations and it is **not** proportional to the identity operator (as it instead happens for a one-particle space). In view of Schur's lemma the representation cannot be irreducible.

An invariant closed subspace is, evidently, the subspace of state vectors where the squared mass $M^2= P_\mu P^\mu$ assumes values (in the sense of spectral decomposition)  inside a fixed interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By "The said representation", do you mean the multiparticle Hilbert space? Furthermore, is $P^\mu P_\mu$ a Casimir operator?

Comment: Yes, I'm making the text clearer.

Comment: Yes, it is a Casimir operator in the sense that it commutes with all the generators of the representation, but it is not a constant, as instead it turns out for one-particle reprs.