# Poincare group and free theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, group-theory, group-representations, poincare-symmetry

How exactly is the Poincare group related to the free relativistic theories in quantum field theory? I know Poincare group is the Lorentz group along with translations but don't see any connected why the field will influence the Poincare group.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a general phenomenon. Whenever a theory/system $S$ has a [symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry),
   it in particular means that some group $G$ [acts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $G\times S \to S$ on the system $S$. The system $S$ then constitutes a (possibly non-linearly realized) *representation* of the group $G$. See also my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/19786/2451).
2. Concretely the [isometry group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_group) of [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) is the [Poincare group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group). Concerning representations of the Poincare group in relativistic field theories, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73593/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100844/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein.

Comment: I mean rotations and translations make sense for scalar fields, as well as vector fields like Electromagnetic field.