# How many elementary particles are predicted by Wigner's classification?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, supersymmetry, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry

My understanding is that when it comes to the correspondence between representation theory and particle physics, every irreducible representation of the Poincare group has a corresponding fundamental particle.

My questions are as follows:

1. are all of the currently known fundamental particles predicted to
   exist by this correspondence idea?
2. does the traditional $ISO(3,1)$
   Poincare group/algebra predict the existence of supersymmetric
   particles?  If not, what superalgebra is needed?

Comment: Related? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224812/why-are-one-particle-states-called-irreducible-representations-of-poincar%C3%A9-group , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100844/representations-of-the-poincare-group

Comment: To clarify: Wigner's classification doesn't predict the existence of particles. It only classifies whatever particles happen to exist. Can questions 1 and 2 be re-worded in a way that still makes sense after that clarification? (For example, 1. do all of the currently known fundamental particles respect Wigner's classification?)

Answer (score 2):

1. No, the Poincare symmetry only predicts relationships between different inertial frames.
2. Again no. One would need a supersymmetric extension of the Poincare group.