# E and B field from Time Varying Current

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

How would I go about calculating the B field and E field from a time varying current charging a capacitor. Theoretically I feel like a solution should exist, but there seems to be a dependence between the two fields that is recursive, the change in the E field makes a change in the B field, but that makes a change in the E field... How do you solve this?q

Comment: I think Griffiths make this point in his E&M book. If I remember correctly, I think the way to get out of the infinite loop you mention is that physically, you will not be able to keep a time varying current going on forever. If you start with zero current you will have to keep every increasing it meaning you would need an infinite energy source. I think in "real" life the current becomes steady fairly quickly and one does not have to worry about these recursive relations.

Comment: You're asking about the E and B fields inside (and around) the capacitor?

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87746

Comment: @BMS everywhere in space