# Proof of Magnetic Fields of Moving Charges

Tags: magnetic-fields

I know that the magnetic field of a moving charge is: $$\vec B=\frac {\mu_0 q  \vec v \times \hat r}{4\pi r^{2}}.$$ I want to know how this formula was derived, so that I can get a better understanding.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Before you ask, you should do some research on your own. Have you read about Biot-Savart's law?

Comment: Before I ask, I actually did some research on my own.I couldn't find the proof. I also read about Biot-Savart. I thought Biot-Savart is used when you have a current carrying wire and a point P at a distance. I was asking about point charges like a single electron or a proton. Is it still applicable?

Comment: The Biot - Savart law is correct to compute the field of a moving charge in the non relativistic limitc. In the general case, you have to use the Liénard–Wiechert potential. You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential

Comment: Related (if not duplicate) : [Magnetic Field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge/413029#413029)

Comment: Would this be better on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, Liénard-Wiechert is what I was looking for. All is clear now.