# Can we understand a moving charge as a dipole?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge, dipole

I work as a physics teacher at a high school and I have to explain these days the magnetic field of a curreny carrying wire. Of course I may just give the formulae and describe how the field $\vec{B}$ looks like. However, I would like to give a bit of insight to them on the physics behind this.

Before that I explained what is a dipole, and then, from that, I explained ferromagnetism. I was wondering if I can explain the $\vec{B}$ created by a moving particle without going into Special Relativity. Thus, I was wondering if a moving charge could be considered as a dipole, since by passing through some material, the negative charge goes forward, and the holes go inwards, so that somehow we have got there a dipole. Could this be somehow a correct intuitive explanation?

Comment: The magnetic field from a moving charge is nothing like a dipole field. For starters, a dipole field drops off proportionally to $1/r^{3}$ while the field (both magnetic and electric) due to moving charge (at constant velocity) drops off proportionally to $1/r^{2}$. I do, however, agree that it would be a bit much to talk about special relativity.

Comment: Related : [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge/413029#413029).

Answer (score 3):

No, this is an incorrect explanation. Even a moving charge in *vacuum* produces a magnetic field.

Answer (score 3):

A magnetic field really is a consequence of relativity. I don't think you can explain the origin of magnetic field without at least knowing something about length contraction in a moving frame of reference.