# How to calculate the total Electromagnetic force exerted by one moving electron on another

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image]

Consider two electrons $e_1$, $e_2$, located at $P_{xyz}$ and $Q_{xyz}$, with velocities $u_{xyz}$ and $v_{xyz}$ respectively in the observer's inertial frame of reference, both with charge $e$.

I wish to determine the instantaneous electro-magnetic forces exerted by $e_1$ on $e_2$. I understand that I firstly need to calculate the Electric Field vector $\bf{E_{1Q}}$ and the Magnetic Field vector $\bf{B_{1Q}}$ which both occur at position Q due to the influence of electron $e_1$.

Secondly I need to determine (and then vector-sum) the forces exerted by those fields on the second electron $e_2$.

From this wikipedia article: [Biot-Savart Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) (section: "Point charge at constant velocity") I obtain expressions (derived by Oliver Heaviside, 1888, from Maxwell's Equations) for the Electric Field vector $E_{1Q}$ and the Magnetic Field vector $B_{1Q}$:-

$$ \bf{E_{1Q}} = \frac{e}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}{\left(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}\sin^2\theta_{ur}\right)^{3/2}}\frac{ \hat{r}  }{\lvert r\rvert^2}$$

where $r$ is the displacement vector $r = Q_{xyz}-P_{xyz}$ ,$\hat{r}$ is the unit vector of $r$ and $\theta_{ur}$ is the angle between $e_1$'s velocity $u_{xyz}$ and $r$.

$$ \bf{B_{1Q}} = \frac{\textbf {u} \times \bf{E_{1Q}} }{c^2} $$

(where $\times$ is the vector product operator).

Next I can find the force $\mathbf{F_m}$ exerted by the **magnetic** field upon electron $e_2$ from the equation:-

$$\mathbf{F_m} = e \left( \bf{v} \times \bf{B_{1Q}} \right)$$

where the direction of $\mathbf{F_m}$ is obtained from Fleming's left-hand Motor rule.

However I am unclear as to how to calculate the force $\mathbf{F_E}$ exerted by the electric field upon target electron $e_2$.  My textbook only gives the equation for the Coulomb force ($\mathbf{F_c}=e.\mathbf{E}$) exerted by an electric field on a **static** electron.  I presume that the target electron velocity $\mathbf{v_{xyz}}$ needs to be taken into account somehow.  Please can somebody tell me how?

UPDATE

As tomtom1-4 answered, I can use the Lorentz Force equation, which in SI units is:-

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{F} = e ( \mathbf{E} +  \mathbf{v}  \times \mathbf{B}) 
\end{equation}

which is equivalent to:-

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{F} = e ( \mathbf{E} +  \mathbf{v}  \times 
\frac{\textbf {u} \times\bf{E} }{c^2}) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{F} = e ( \mathbf{\hat{r}} \vert E\vert +  \mathbf{v}  \times 
\frac{\textbf {u} \times \mathbf{\hat{r}} \vert E\vert }{c^2}) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{F} = e \vert E\vert \left(  \mathbf{\hat{r}}  + \frac{1}{c^2}  \mathbf{v}  \times 
(\textbf {u} \times \mathbf{\hat{r}}  ) \right).
\end{equation}

Substituting for $\vert E \vert$ using the Heaviside expression for $E_{1Q}$ gives:-

\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{F} =   
\frac{ee}{4\pi\epsilon_0  r ^2} 
\left[\frac{1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}}{\left(1-\frac{u^2}{c^2}\sin^2\theta_{ur}\right)^{3/2}}\right]
\left(  \mathbf{\hat{r}}  
+ \frac{\mathbf{v}  \times (\textbf {u} \times \mathbf{\hat{r}}  )}{c^2}   \right).
\end{equation}

For comparison here is the formula from Thomas Fritsch's (Darwin-based) answer:-
$$\mathbf{F}=\frac{ee}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}
\left(\hat{\mathbf{r}} +
\frac{
   \mathbf{u}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{v})
  +\mathbf{v}(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{u})
  -\hat{\mathbf{r}}[\mathbf{u}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}+3(\mathbf{u}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}})(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{v})]
}{2 c^2} 
\right).$$

As per Ján Lalinský's comments, I'm beginning to see how, even in Galilean relativity, timing considerations make the situation I describe more complicated in terms of the time-variant E & B fields at point Q than they would be in the case of, for example, a Biot-Savart steady current element at point P.

Comment: Related : [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge/413029#413029). See equations (01a) and (01b) in my answer.

Comment: @Frobenius, thanks I'm having a look at your answer there.

Comment: @Frobenius, thanks.I see that those equations (for E and B fields) match the Heaviside equations.  Nice diagrams - what tool did you use?

Comment: GeoGebra. It's free. We can insert equations in $\LaTeX$. Note that the Figures in above link are 3D-drawings. See the arrows of the vectors.

Comment: @Froebenius. Thanks very much (inserted a basic 2D picture).

Comment: Well done for the picture !!!

Comment: There are approximate expressions that are usable in cases where radiation/retardation is negligible such as the Darwin Lagrangian - implied fields of moving charges. However, these do not and can't give the force exactly, because of special relativity which requires that the force can't be a function of instantaneous values of position, velocities, accelerations only (there is no concept of simultaneity for two electrons).

Comment: Finite speed of interaction means the real force differs from those simple approximations by a part that can be related to radiation or force retardation. In other words, the forces depend on more things than just positions, velocities and accelerations of the particles. There is a so-called Feynman-Heaviside formula which takes this problem into account in case the fields are purely retarded, see https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_21.html

Comment: @Ján Lalinský  thanks for the link and elucidations. I'm beginning to see how, even in Galilean relativity, timing considerations make the situation I describe more complicated in terms of the E & B fields at point Q than they would be in the case of e.g. a Biot-Savart steady current element.

Answer (score 1):

No, what you have should be correct. The force on a charge $e$ from an electromagnetic field is given by the Lorenz force
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{F} = e ( \mathbf{E} + \frac{\mathbf{v}}{c} \times \mathbf{B}) .
\end{equation}
You have seperated this into the parts of the electric and magnetic field. But the formula
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{F}_\mathbf{E} = e \mathbf{E} 
\end{equation}
still holds. And it is independent of the velocity of the second electron.

Comment: Thanks, I'd forgotten about the Lorentz force equation. I note your equation for $F$ is in cgs units. (I need to check my units are consistent!)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for something like the Darwin interaction.

The simple Newton-Coulomb Lagrangian of two charged particles (in SI-units)
$$L=\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2-\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$$
can be improved by

- handling both particles relativistically,
- describing one particle reacting to the
  electric and magnetic field generated by the other particle,
- and then Taylor-expanding up to terms of order $\frac{1}{c^2}$

Then you get the [Darwin Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Lagrangian) (in SI-units), given by
$$\begin{align}
L&=\frac{1}{2}m_1v_1^2+\frac{1}{8c^2}m_1v_1^4 \\
 &+\frac{1}{2}m_2v_2^2+\frac{1}{8c^2}m_2v_2^4 \\
 &-\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} \\
 &+\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\frac{1}{2c^2}
  [\mathbf{v}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}_2+(\mathbf{v}_1\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}})(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_2)]
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

You see:

- It still describes the interaction as an instantaneous interaction,
  depending only on the *current* positions and velocities of the two particles.
  By doing so it neglects any retardation effects
  due to the electromagnetic field propagating with the finite speed of light.
- The third line of (1) is the well-known Coulomb interaction.
- The fourth line is a magnetic interaction (the so-called Darwin interaction).

From this Lagrangian (1) you can find the [equations of motions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_Lagrangian#Interacting_particles)
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\mathbf{p}_1}{dt}&=\frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}} \\
&+ \frac{q_1q_2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}\frac{1}{2 c^2}\{
   \mathbf{v}_1(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_2)
  +\mathbf{v}_2(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_1)
  -\hat{\mathbf{r}}[\mathbf{v}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}_2+3(\mathbf{v}_1\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}})(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\cdot\mathbf{v}_2)]
  \} \\
\frac{d\mathbf{p}_2}{dt}&=\text{similar as above with $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ replaced by $-\hat{\mathbf{r}}$}  
\end{align}$$

The first term on the right side is the well-known Coulomb force.
The second term on the right side is a magnetic force
(proportional to the velocities of the two particles,
and with a quite complicated directional dependency).

Comment: Thanks I need to ponder this. (Note to self this uses cgs units). I'm not clear what ̂ ̂  means?

Comment: @steveOw The $\hat{\mathbf{r}}\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ used in the Wikipedia
article seems to be meant as the tensor product.
I have resolved this tensor product to make it easier.
I also added the $4\pi\epsilon_0$ factors to make the
equations SI-conform, instead of the CGS equations from Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful to me!

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the Feynman-Heaviside formula (referred to in comments to my question by Ján Lalinský) is a more accurate formula because it does take into account "the retardation effects due to the electromagnetic field propagating with the finite speed of light" which you mentioned in your answer.