# (Special relativity) A tilted dipole composed of $+q$ and $-q$ point charges moves at a horizontal velocity. Will it rotate?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, dipole

Two point charges $+q$ and $-q$ are connected with a rigid insulating stick:

[image]

This dipole moves at a velocity $v$ to the right. Therefore, the charges should exert a magnetic Lorentz force $F_B$ on each other, causing the dipole to rotate.

On the other hand, we can find an inertial frame *S* in which the charges are at rest from the start. Then, according to the [transformation formulas for velocities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Standard_configuration), how can this dipole rotate (i.e., with the charges having a non-zero vertical component in their velocities) in another inertial frame that moves at a velocity of $v$ to the left with respect to the frame *S*?

Comment: They feel electrical attraction along the line connecting them. In addition, each of them produces a magnetic field when it moves, and that magnetic field gives a magnetic Lorentz force to another moving charge. The magnetic forces create a torque to rotate the dipole.

Comment: I believe they create magnetic fields perpendicular to their velocities, so that there is no Lorentz force due to it.

Comment: @Pedro Doesn't Lorentz force come from the "cross product" of the velocity and the magnetic field? Therefore being perpendicular seems to be an optimal case.

Comment: Oh, right, my bad.

Comment: I think the red arrows should point opposite to what they're pointing now, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Pedro You may think of the pair as currents flowing in opposite directions.
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/wirfor.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the Lorentz transformation formula for the electric field, we have:

$$
\mathbf E_\perp' = \gamma(\mathbf E_\perp+\mathbf v\times \mathbf B_\perp)
$$

Since $\mathbf B=0$ in the rest frame, in the moving frame $\mathbf E$ becomes stronger by a factor of $\gamma$. We might hope for these effects to cancel out. The size of the magnetic field generated is $|B_\perp| = \gamma v|E_\perp|/c^2$, by a similar Lorentz transformation law.

Lorentz force on the moving charge will be $qv|B_\perp|$, since the field is perpendicular to the direction of motion. So the overall force due to magnetic field is $\gamma |E_\perp| qv^2/c^2$. Meanwhile, the magnitude of the electric force on the charge in the direction perpendicular to motion is $\gamma |E_\perp| q$. Since these are pointing in opposite directions, the net attractive force, perpendicular to the direction of motion, is:

$$
\gamma |E_\perp|q(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}|E_\perp|q(1-v^2/c^2) = |E_\perp|q\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}
$$

But this is not a complete cancellation, the perpendicular electromagnetic force is still reduced in the moving frame. The only hope now is that maybe in the moving frame, the insulating stick applies a force that *isn't parallel to itself*.

In the resting frame, the stick transmits a force $F$ between the two charges. The definition of force is $dp/dt$: the rate of flow of momentum. In the resting frame, both charges have 0 momentum at all times. So the net momentum change is 0. Some momentum is flowing through the electric field between the charges at a rate of $F$, and an equal and opposite quantity of momentum is flowing through the insulating stick, also at a rate of $F$.

Let's consider the change in force applied by the stick after our Lorentz transformation. In the rest frame, we have time coordinate $t$. In the moving frame, we have time coordinate $t' = \gamma(t-vx/c^2)$. At rest, $x=0$ at all times, so $t' = \gamma t$. This means that a small interval of time $dt$ in the rest frame corresponds to a slightly longer interval of time in the moving frame, $dt'=\gamma dt$. The momentum transferred in a time $dt$ is $dp = (Fdt\cos\alpha, Fdt\sin\alpha)$ in the rest frame. According to the transformation rule for 4 momentum, perpendicular momentum transferred remains unchanged while parallel momentum transferred scales by $\gamma$. So we have: $dp'=(\gamma Fdt\cos\alpha, Fdt\sin\alpha)$. Then:

$$
F' = \frac{dp'}{dt'} = \frac{\gamma Fdt\cos\alpha, Fdt\sin\alpha}{\gamma dt} = (F\cos\alpha, \frac{1}{\gamma}F\sin\alpha)
$$

So the force exerted by the stick perpendicular to the direction of motion has been scaled by a factor of $1/\gamma$, just like the perpendicular electromagnetic force was, while parallel force remains the same. Mystery solved, but in a very strange way: The moving stick is exerting a force along a different axis than the one it's pointing in. But that's just special relativity for you. (Length contraction doesn't compensate for this, in fact it makes the stick even less parallel to the force it transfers!)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your detailed answer, especially the key insight that the moving stick applies a force that isn't parallel to itself!

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something. Then the stick *rotates* in the moving inertial frame (force not parallel to the stick), but it *doesn't* in the rest frame? I apologise, I must be the only one who didn't get the solution to the (apparent) paradox.

Comment: @Ricky Tensor Great answers including knzhou.  Those are some crazy contortions!  I was very happy with Newton.  Why did Einstein have to come along and ruin everything?

Comment: I have another question: now let's consider the stick itself. It's receiving reaction forces at both ends that are not parallel to itself. Then why doesn't it rotate?

Comment: @isend Now I'm confused all over again! If nobody answers this and I don't manage to figure it out, I'll put a second bounty on the question or maybe start a new one.

Comment: @isend Consider the forces on one of the tips of the stick. There's a force pushing outwards from the rest of the stick, and a force pushing inwards from contact with the charge. These forces are equal and opposite, so the tip of the stick doesn't accelerate. In the moving frame, all these forces transform in the same way, so while they may now be pointing in different directions, they will still be equal and opposite. The diagram for the tips of the stick is basically the same as your diagram for the charges, but with $F_\text{em}$ replaced by the contact force with the charge.

Comment: @knzhou When calculating "torques", things get more nonintuitive because one needs to consider "simultaneity" for forces that do not occur at the same position (see https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1119/1.1975612 ). I think Ricky Tensor's answer is still correct. And it's also true that the stick does *not* rotate under these reaction forces. You need to switch back to the frame where the forces at its two ends occur "simultaneously" to correctly calculate the lever arm in the new frame, and eventually you will get a zero angular impulse for the stick.

Comment: @RickyTensor Thanks. It's a good point to think about all the "one-point" "contact" forces along the stick, since it avoids different positions that lead to non-simultaneity.

Comment: @isend That paper is very interesting, thanks! I think that solves the problem. Of course, Ricky Tensor's answer is perfectly correct, I was just wondering how the torque analysis works out. (Incidentally, I think that if you take the idea of the paper and go down to infinitesimal elements, then it reduces to the second point I made, about shear stress being hard to define outside of the rest frame.)

Comment: @isend : I am not convinced from the proof of SANFORD ARANOFF in his paper. His argument about the non-simultaneity (of the applied magnetic forces by which he proves that the torque is zero) does not exist if you consider the dipole moving in an inertial system and find $\mathbf E, \mathbf B$ using the relativistic equations produced by Lienard-Wiechert potentials for the field of a uniformly   
moving charge  instead of those $\mathbf E, \mathbf B$ found as Lorentz transforms of the rest frame of the dipole.

Comment: @isend : For the relativistic equations produced by Lienard-Wiechert potentials for the field of a uniformly moving charge (referred in my previous comment)  see my answer here [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge/413029#413029).

Comment: @Frobenius It's difficult to analyze the "non-simultaneity" of electromagnetic forces, because the em forces are *always* there. That's why Aranoff uses two *impulse* forces instead in his model to allow the readers to see this unavoidable non-simultaneity in a new frame for two events at different locations, despite that his original intention was also to prove that a pair of moving charges do not rotate. Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths also mentions the non-simultaneity of non-contact forces (i.e., incompatibility of Newton's third law) in Chapter 12, although only briefly.

Answer (score 8):

Ricky Tensor has beaten me to the punch, and his excellent answer provides the key insight: in the frame where the stick is moving, the force of the stick on the charges is not parallel to the stick itself. In my answer I'll just provide some intuition for why this should be the case.

### Simpler setup, no angles

The necessity of this result can be seen in a much simpler setup. Consider a stretchable string connecting two equal masses, which has a constant tension $T$ in its rest frame. If the masses start off at rest, they will come together and collide due to the string.

[image]

Now consider the reference frame where the masses are initially moving with velocity $v$ to the right. As the string accelerates the masses towards each other, the rightward velocity $v_x$ must stay the same, so the speed goes up, and the Lorentz factor $\gamma$ increases. But the rightward momentum is $p_x = \gamma m v_x$, which means $p_x$ must increase, which means there must be a force in the rightward direction. This force must be applied by the string itself, meaning that the force it applies is not parallel to itself.

(There is a second subtlety in this particular setup: if the string is exerting rightward forces on both particles, doesn't that violate conservation of momentum? No, because the string itself carries rightward momentum; it must carry an energy per length of $T$, which means it has a mass per length of $T/c^2$. As the string's length decreases, it gives up its momentum. But this is irrelevant to OP's question, since OP's stick has constant length.)

### Defining shear stress

Here's a second way to see that this result is plausible. The reason the non-parallel force looks weird is because it suggests that there is a shear stress in the stick, while no such shear stress exists in the stick's rest frame. This would be a contradiction, since, e.g. we could replace OP's stick with a cylindrical fluid-filled balloon, which can't support shear stress at all.

The problem here is in the definition of shear stress. Demanding the force be along the stick is equivalent to demanding that the off-diagonal elements of the stress tensor vanish, $T_{ij} = 0$ if $i \neq j$. But this condition doesn't remain true under a Lorentz transformation, which mixes up diagonal and off-diagonal elements! The real definition of vanishing shear stress, from the solid's point of view, is that the off-diagonal elements are zero *in the solid's rest frame*. The constitutive relations of a solid only apply in the rest frame. In a general frame, all bets are off.

### A microscopic model

The second explanation above might feel like a cop-out; it just says that there's no reason the stick's force has to be parallel to itself. But you might want a concrete, microscopic model that explains *how* the stick's force could be non-parallel to itself.

Of course, this would be rather difficult to do for a real solid, but here's a toy model. Let's replace the stick with a hollow column, within which is a single neutral particle. In the stick's rest frame, this particle elastically bounces back and forth, reflecting its velocity every time it hits one of the charges, leading to a time-averaged force along the stick.

Now let's consider the same situation in OP's reference frame. The particle still bounces back and forth, reversing its velocity every time it hits one of the charges. But because the stick itself is moving, *the particle's velocity is not along the stick*. It needs an additional rightward component to stay inside the stick as the stick moves to the right. This is the origin of the non-parallel force.

In principle, something similar is happening at the microscopic level in a real solid, though this would be very hard to show explicitly.

Comment: Excellent clarification.  I was about to ask why the stick didn't rotate.

Answer (score 6):

Here I am providing a shorter version of Ricky Tensor's excellent answer to this question.

In the frame where the dipole is at rest, each of the charges feels an electro(magnetic) force along the line connecting the two charges, and a stick force of the same magnitude but in the opposite direction, hence in a state of equilibrium.

In the frame where the dipole is moving horizontally, the horizontal length is contracted because of Lorentz contraction, and the perpendicular force is reduced according to force transformation from a rest frame to a moving frame:

$$
F'_\perp = \frac{1}{\gamma}F_\perp
$$
$$
F'_{||} = F_{||}
$$

This force formula applies not only to the stick force $F_\mathrm{s}$, but also to the electromagnetic force $F_\mathrm{em}$:

[image]

Therefore, each charge is again in a state of equilibrium, though now moving at a constant velocity.