# Magnetic field due to a finite-length straight wire carrying a constant current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, magnetostatics

**My question**: I want to find an expression at any point in space for the magnetic field $\mathbf B$ produced by a straight wire of *finite* length $L$ carrying a constant current $I$.

I think that we can simplify our analysis by using cylindrical coordinates, and by placing the wire along the $z$ axis such that the center of the wire is at the origin; we assume the current flows in the positive $z$ direction. So the diagram would be the following:

[image: 1]

---

**My attempt**: Below I show my procedure which I initially wrote in Microsoft Word. I think it'd be a waste of time to translate it to Latex, but if you ask for it, I'll do it.

*Image 1/4*:

[image: Step 1]

*Image 2/4*:

[image: Step 2]

*Image 3/4*:

[image: Step 3]

*Image 4/4*:

[image: Step 4]

*End of the computations*.

Here's a plot in Wolfram Mathematica assuming $I = 10 \text{ A}$ and $L = 10 \text{ m}$:

[image: Magnetic field density due to a finite-length straight wire in the z axis centered at the origin and carrying a constant current]

Now, there are some reasons why I think my formula for $\mathbf B$ could be correct:

- The magnitude of the field is inversely proportional to the perpendicular distance $\rho_0$ between the wire and the point $P$. So the farther the point is from the wire, the weaker the field, as expected.
- The direction of the field is in accordance with the right-hand rule.
- In the extreme/particular case of an infinite wire, the formula simplifies to the well-known formula obtained from Ampère's law (in magnetostatics *i.e.* without Maxwell's correction).

However, I'm a bit hesitant because I haven't touched vector calculus nor electromagnetic theory since I took a class about 1.5 years ago; I had to review many mathematical equations to answer this question. So I'm asking you to check my work to see if there're no mistakes.

By the way, I'd be more grateful if you could manage to simplify the general expression I got.

Comment: I do not find any errors here. It is perfect, although I have never tried to find Magnetic field due a finite straight wire using the cylindrical co-ordinates; it is very interesting.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi $z_0$ is the $z$ coordinate of the point $P$ where we're computing the field, while $l$ is the position vector of the differential current segment. The integral is w.r.t. to the variable $z$ ($z$ direction), however this is the same as $l$ (not $z_0$) because they're parallel. Am I still mistaken?

Comment: Yes, I removed my comment as soon as I realised my mistake.

Comment: Whoops, I just noticed you deleted the first comment and posted another. I'll keep my previous comment in case some else gets confused with my notation. Thanks BTW.

Comment: To find the magnetic field due to a finite-length straight wire carrying a constant current has no sense (it violates the continuity equation). See my answer and comments here [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge).

Comment: @Frobenius Yes, a straight wire alone carrying current wouldn't make physical sense. But, the thing is I actually want to calculate the magnetic field due to a rectangular loop of wire, so I thought I could first find the magnetic field due to each of the four straight sides of the loop (hence this question) and then apply superposition. I thought it was unnecessary to say this in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, and it can be arrived at more easily. Consider a finite line current on the $x$-axis, and an observation point which is parallel to the $x$-axis offset at $d_0 \hat z$. (In the image below, it is shown on the $z$-axis.)

[image]

We have $\mathbf r = x \hat x  + d_0 \hat z$ as the observation point, and $\mathbf r' = x' \hat x$ as the source point. The Biot-Savart law gives

$$
\mathbf B(\mathbf r) = \frac{\mu I}{4\pi} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{d\mathbf s' \times (\mathbf r - \mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|^3} \\[2em]
= \frac{\mu I}{4\pi} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{\sin \theta\ d x'}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|^2}
$$
Where $\theta$ is the angle between the current direction $\hat s = \hat x$ and the displacement vector $|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|$. This is derived using the fact that $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b = |a||b|\sin \theta$. You can confirm that the angle $\theta$ here is the same as that shown in the diagram.

Expand the denominator in the integrand,
$$
\frac{\sin \theta}{(x'-x)^2+d_0^2}
$$
And note from the diagram above that for angle $\phi$ as shown, $\sin \theta = \cos \phi = \frac{d_0}{(x'-x)^2+d_0^2}$. Our integral would be simpler if we integrate over the angle $\phi$ instead of the rectilinear $x'$, and we can do this using e.g.
$$
\phi = \arctan \left(\frac{x'-x}{y_0}\right)
$$
(again seen directly from the image of the triangle above), and the differential becomes
$$
dx' = d\phi \frac{1}{d_0} ((x'-x)^2+y_0^2)
$$
Which cancels out in the original integral, making it, after substitution,
$$
|\mathbf B| = \frac{\mu I}{4\pi d_0} \int_{\phi_1}^{\phi_2} \cos \phi d\phi = \frac{\mu I}{4\pi d_0} (\sin \phi_2 - \sin \phi_1)
$$
Where $\phi_1$ is the angle made when $x'=-L/2$, and $\phi_2$ is the angle made when $x'=+L/2$, for a given value of $x$. We have then
$$
\sin \phi_2 - \sin \phi_1 = \frac{a-x}{\sqrt{(a-x)^2+d_0^2}} + \frac{a+x}{\sqrt{(a+x)^2+d_0^2}}
$$
Where $a=L/2$. And therefore the magnitude of the magnetic field is
$$
|\mathbf B| = \frac{\mu I}{4\pi d_0} \left(\frac{a-x}{\sqrt{(a-x)^2+d_0^2}} + \frac{a+x}{\sqrt{(a+x)^2+d_0^2}}\right)
$$
The direction $\hat B$ is always in the same direction when parallel to the current-carrying wire, as it is the mutual perpendicular of the displacement vector and the direction of current flow. Thus it obeys the right-hand rule for all $x$, and $\hat H = -\hat y$.

This is the same result as you obtained, but for a current along the $x$-axis, making the transformations $\rho_0 \rightarrow d_0, L/2 \rightarrow a, z_0 \rightarrow x$, and using a cylindrical unit vector $\hat \phi$.

Needless to say, this expression is not physically meaningful on its own, but it can be used for superposition.