# Direction of magnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

Does magnetic force act along the line joining the centres like gravitational and electric forces do?

Are the directions of magnetic field and magnetic lines of force the same? I have read that the direction of the field is tangential to the direction of the line of force.

Comment: Related : [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge).

Answer (score 2):

(a) "Does magnetic force act along the line joining the centres [...] ? The centres of *what*? You need to specify whether the forces are between current-carrying wires or between magnets or something else.

Note that electrostatic and gravitational forces do act along the lines between the centres of *spherically symmetrical* charge or mass distributions, but this does not hold for every shape of body.

(b) "Are the directions of magnetic field and magnetic lines of force the same?" Yes, a magnetic line of force (or magnetic field line) is *defined* as a line whose direction at every point along it is the direction of the magnetic field at that point. The direction of the line at a point is the direction of the tangent to the line at the point. There's no difference.

Comment: I'm comfortable with using a line to represent the direction of a magnetic field; not so much with a magnetic line of force. The force on a charged object moving across a magnetic field is perpendicular to the direction of the field (and the velocity).

Comment: 'Magnetic line of force' is indeed a misnomer, but it used to be used to mean a magnetic field line, such as one could plot with a plotting compass. I assumed that the questioner was using it in this way, but maybe I'm wrong.