# Difference between uniform and non-uniform conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, terminology, definition, conductors

Am I correct to say that a uniform conductor is cylindrical, while a non-uniform conductor can have any geometry as long as it is open at both ends.

The textbook does not seem to define these 'uniform' or 'non-uniform' conductors.

Comment: Related : [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration is performed on a path, usually a section of a circuit

$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = - \dfrac{\mu}{4 \pi} \displaystyle \int_{\mathbf{r}' \in\ell}  i \dfrac{\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}' }{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3} \times d \mathbf{r}'$.

So far, this is a equation of physics. When you need to evaluate this integral, you usually need to describe the path $\ell$ in a parametric way, i.e. the points of the path $\ell$ in space are function of a parameter $s$, namely $\mathbf{r}'(s)$. It's convenient to use a regular parametrization, so that each point of the path is associated with one value of the parameter $s$.

The choice of the parametrization induces the extreme of integration as well, being $\mathbf{r}_0 = \mathbf{r}(s_0)$ the starting point of the path, and $\mathbf{r}_1 = \mathbf{r}(s_1)$ the other extreme point, so that you can recast the integral as

$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) =  - \dfrac{\mu}{4 \pi}\displaystyle \int_{s_0}^{s_1}  i \dfrac{\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'(s) }{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'(s)|^3} \times \dfrac{d \mathbf{r}'(s)}{ds} ds$

On the other hand, you can write

$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}) = \displaystyle \int_{\mathbf{r}' \in \ell} d\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')$, being

$d\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}') = -  \dfrac{\mu}{4 \pi}  i \dfrac{\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}' }{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3} \times d \mathbf{r}'$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've added my attempt to include limits of integration above. Let me know if anything is wrong.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry I have not done vector calculus or line integrals. Only really single variable.

Comment: Once you manage to write the curve in a parametric way $\mathbf{r}(s)$, it's single variable integration :). You have to do it properly, but then it's single variable integration

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Sorry why do you not have limits of integration like I included?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! :) Just one question, why did you do a line integral? I thought the Bio-Savart Law was for a point?

Comment: Integration means summation, $\mathbf{r}' \in \ell$ indicates the place where we need to perform the integration, in space. Once you write $\mathbf{r}(s)$, you may write the limits of integration of your parameter. I think it doesn't have much sense to write $\int_0^{B}$. Trust me, since I did all the courses of Math and Classical Physics

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I don't have too much knowledge. I'm just studying Bio-Savart Law for first year physics. I'm guessing that what they discuss in Purcell's?

Comment: $\mathbf{r}$ is the "passive" point where we are calculating the field, generated by all the "active" points $\mathbf{r}'$ of the wire. Since we need to evaluate the overall effect of all the points $\mathbf{r}' \in \ell$, we need to sum their contributions and thus performing the line integral $\int_{\mathbf{r}' \in \ell} d\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')$

Comment: Thanks again for you comments! Ok could we not just integrate each component of the B-field? (Like what is the simplest way to solve my confusion)

Comment: One of the things I'm confused on is the notation. I don't know what dB(r, r') means sorry. The only notation I know is boldface B for vector B_x for x-component and etc for each component of vector. Would you mine using my notation please?