# Confusion about vectors in Biot - Savart Law

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

In the formula of the law, we have to find the cross product of the distance(r) and the infinitely small part of the conductor dl.
My doubt is why are these both considered as vectors ? Aren't they measurements of lengths ?

I'm unable to relate vectors with this concept, kindly help me out :)

Comment: This quantity represents the vector change of some given path over an interval dt, Given some parameterization, $\vec{r}(t) = x(t)\hat I + y(t)\hat j + z(t)\hat z$ $ \vec{dr} = \vec{r'(t)} dt$

Comment: Related : [Magnetic field due to a single moving charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412924/magnetic-field-due-to-a-single-moving-charge).