# What exactly is quantum spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

What is "spin" as it relates to subatomic particles? I've heard that it's similar to angular momentum but I've also heard that's not completely the case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Spin is the total angular momentum, or intrinsic angular momentum, of a body. The spins of elementary particles are analogous to the spins of macroscopic bodies. you can look at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_%28physics%29