# Are black hole singularities fermions?

Tags: black-holes, energy-conservation, fermions, quantum-gravity, singularities

I was just wondering. I apologize if this is a dumb question. Is it possible that the mass of a black hole is converted into quantum energy that gets distributed across the universe uniformly so that everything has mass?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. More specifically, the title and body seem to ask different things (and neither of the questions is really clear). Please add further information about the context so that other users will know exactly what the issue here is.

Comment: A couple of points : (1) there's no special "quantum energy", it's all just energy. (2) Fermions have *spin* but that spin is not quite the same as the concept of classical angular momentum macroscopic objects have - see [What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172438/what-exactly-is-quantum-spin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The angular momentum of a black hole is the total angular momentum of everything it has absorbed. A black hole can take in fermions and bosons. Nothing limits it to half integer spin.

Comment: Okay, thanks for answering my crazy question.