# Rest mass energy of electron

Tags: special-relativity, mass, electrons, quantum-spin

For electron's energy why we some time use the word "REST MASS ENERGY" why we use this word as electron is always spinning?

Comment: Read through [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/50583) first. "Spin" doesn't mean there's something like a classical particle spinning. "Rest mass" is just the square of the four-momentum of a thing.

Comment: Yeah ! but the main point is not of spin . If spin doesn't actually occur there can occur orbital motion . But practically how does electron can be at rest ?

Comment: it means the [invariant mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_mass) of the electron, which is a [nice solid unchanging value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_rest_mass) that doesn't depend on whether it is spinning or orbiting or whatever other possible motion.

Comment: one electron is always at rest in its self frame. If it measures itself with a energy.mass.meter, it will get its own rest mass

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of the electron as a particle; it just looks like a particle when you observe it. The rest of the time, it is described by a wave function: a probability of finding it in a particular state *if observed*. We say the electron is "at rest" if the expected position, in our frame of reference, is independent of time - in other words, its center of mass is not moving.

"Spin" is a property of an electron that can be observed when the electron interacts with a magnetic field: the spin can be aligned with the field, or counter-aligned, and this gives rise to a different energy state. But we don't consider the electron as "moving" because it has spin.

Answer (score -2):

Please excuse me for rephrasing the question:

> Why use the phrase "REST MASS ENERGY" when the electron is always spinning?

Because the electron isn't actually spinning. It isn't some billiard-ball thing rotating like a planet. Instead it has a wave nature, wherein electron spin is *intrinsic* spin. It's what makes it what it is. For an analogy, think of a tornado. It has intrinsic spin. If it didn't, it wouldn't *be* a tornado. If you could somehow remove that rotation, it wouldn't be a tornado any more. It's similar for an electron. It's a spin ½ particle. It has intrinsic spin. If it didn't, it wouldn't *be* an electron. If you could somehow remove that spin, it wouldn't be an electron any more.

The nature of it is not clear in the literature, but note that the [Einstein-de Haas effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect) demonstrates  *"that spin angular momentum is indeed of the same nature as the angular momentum of rotating bodies as conceived in classical mechanics".* Also Google on [electron standing wave](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=electron+standing+wave) and note that in [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties) electrons *"exist as standing waves"*. A standing wave looks motionless, but it isn't. You can see an example of such hidden motion in the [Poynting vector for static fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#Static_fields). There's a circular flow of electromagnetic energy. And whilst this isn't actually at rest, it isn't going anywhere with respect to you, so it's *effectively* at rest.

You can relate this to Einstein's [E=mc²](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/www/) paper: *"The mass of a body is a measure of its energy-content"*. When you trap a massless photon [in a mirror box](http://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06478), it increases the mass of that system. It's still going round and round inside the box at c, but it's *effectively* at rest, and the box is harder to move because the photon is in there. Then when you open the box, it's a radiating body that loses mass. But until you do, that energy is effectively at rest, and we call it rest-mass energy.