# What is actually spinning in quantum spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, elementary-particles

Some texts say quantum spin is analogous to the spin of a planet in that it gives a particle angular momentum and a magnetic moment. However, as subatomic particles are tiny, the surfaces of charged particles would have to be moving faster than the speed of light in order to produce the measured magnetic moments!
If the particle is not physically spinning, is anything spinning?
Is the particle's wave function spinning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/)

Comment: Doesn’t Spin have enormous consequences, in addition to telling us about a particle’s intrinsic angular momentum. Particles with integral Spin (bosons) have symmetric wavefunctions whereas particles with Spin ½ (fermions) have symmetric wavefunctions. As consequence spin ½ wave functions lie on top of each other and cancel out giving zero possibility of this situation being permitted (Pauli Exclusion Principle).