# Is muon a point particle?

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, elementary-particles, point-particles

Im just a beginner in particle physics. As I have understand, electrons are considered as a point particle whose spin has nothing to do with original rotation around own axis but an intrinsic quantum number.

But muon can be considered as a heavy electron that decays into electron.can we say muon actually rotates around itself in external magnetic field? Or it is also a point like particle? How can I know?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/2451 and links therein.

Comment: As far as we know, muons are point particles just like electrons. You are confusing a spinning charged particle’s spin precession in a magnetic field with the spin itself. It has spin (intrinsic angular momentum), and in a magnetic field that spin can precess so that it doesn’t point in a constant direction.