# About the spin of fundamental particle

Tags: quantum-spin

What if the spin of electron or of any fundamental particle is same as ball/top spinning,is there will be any change in physics rule?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is spin as it relates to subatomic particles?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-is-spin-as-it-relates-to-subatomic-particles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spin of particles can be described as simple value, like +1\2 or -1\2 for electron.

In your case spin will have to be described as two angles.

Currently electrons, as they pass the magnetic field, are deflected one way for a specific amount, or another way, for the same amout of deflection. Depending if their spin is positive or negative.

In your case electrons would be deflected in some random direction, according to how their ball-spin axis is located. Not just two options, but a whole range of options.

That is not the case. So simple models of 'ball-spin' are thrown away because they dont predict the experiment.

I would say spin is just a bad name. It has nothing to do with physical object spinning. Differences are too great.

Comment: In defense of the term "spin", it is true that it is a little unfortunate, but I think that it is only confusing for beginners. Actually it has a pretty logical reason behind the name, and it is that when you calculate the angular momentum operator for a dirac field, it has two contributions. One comes from its actual angular momentum, but the other one is completely new. As, classically, the only other possible contribution to angular momentum is if the object is itself spinning, they decided to also call this new property spin.

Comment: Also to add to @tonetillo4 , spin assignments  to particles are necessary in order to keep angular momentum conservation at the level of particle interactions.